# Problem with jeditable plugin

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, jeditable

Problem with jeditable. Want to change user information on the fly but it doesn't work. during debugging it shows POST ok, no error, no success

My code (index.php)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dblclick").editable("change.php", { 
    submitdata : {userid: "<?=$id?>"},
     id   : 'elementid',
     name : 'newvalue',
      indicator : "<img src='styles/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif'>",
      tooltip   : "click to edit",
      event     : "dblclick",
      style  : "inherit"
  });
  });
  </script>
...
<div id="fullname" class="dblclick" ><?=$person->fullname?></div>
```

change.php

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$id=$_POST['userid'];
$field=$_POST['elementid'];
$newvalue=$_POST['newvalue'];
if(isset ($id) && isset($field) && isset($newvalue) )
{$query =  $db->query("UPDATE usr_table  SET '$field'='$newvalue' WHERE id = '$id'")  or die(mysqli_errno());
    }
?>
```

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use backticks around column names, not quotes. However, I must note that the way this code is written is **extremely** insecure. You should never, ever put GET POST variables directly into a database query.

This is better:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';

function fail($msg) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    die($msg);
}

$id = (int)@$_POST['userid'];
if (!$id) fail('User ID invalid or missing.', 404);

$field = @$_POST['elementid'];
$allowed_fields = array('fullname','dob','phone','adress','school','info');
if (!in_array($field, $allowed_fields)) fail('Invalid or missing field.', 404);

$newvalue = $db->real_escape_string(@$_POST['newvalue']);

$db->query("UPDATE usr_table SET `$field`='$newvalue' WHERE id=$id") or fail($db->error);

$q = $db->query("SELECT `$field` from usr_table where id=$id") or fail($db->error);
if ($r = $q->fetch_row()) echo $r[0];
else fail('User not found.');
```